# Elastic 6 on docker : can not set a password

Tags: docker, authentication, elasticsearch, docker-compose, kibana

I have a docker-compose file and I am trying to have elasticsearch and kibana inside.

The problem : I am setting the ELASTIC_PASSWORD in the environnment but the authentification system is failing and my elastic is expose.

What is wrong ?

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  elasticsearch:
    container_name: 'elasticsearch'
    image: 'docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.7.1'
    environment:
      - node.name=es01
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - xpack.security.enabled=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1g -Xmx1g"
      - network.host=0.0.0.0
      - ELASTIC_PASSWORD=mySuperPassword
    ulimits:
      nproc: 65535
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    cap_add:
      - ALL
    privileged: true
    volumes:
      - api_esdata1:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9300:9300
  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.7.1
    container_name: kibana
    environment:
      SERVER_NAME: localhost
      ELASTICSEARCH_URL: http://127.0.0.1:9200/
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
    links:
      - elasticsearch
volumes:
  api_esdata1:
    external: true
```

Comment: Do you have a license? Basic authentication in Elasticsearch is only included with the basic license from versions 6.8 and 7.1, you are using 6.7.1, a version where the security features need a paid license.

Comment: Thank you it was that. I upgraded my Elastic version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @leandrojmp said, Basic authentification in Elasticsearch starting only from 6.8 versions. I upgraded the version and now it works well.